# How to make a GUI that plots user-entered function(x)?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm developing a program that takes a function of x from the user, also it takes the min and max values of x, then the program have to plot this function.
for example:

user-entered function(x) is: `x^2+2x-1`
Max value of x is : `3`
Min value of x is : `-3`

now the GUI have to display **(if the entered function is free of errors otherwise the error will be displayed to the user)** something similar to this image:
[image]

The entered function also maybe a little bit complex E.g.(sin(x), cos(2*x+1), etc..)

I'm trying to make this job with C++ and QT, so any advice how to make the plotting part of the program using QT, or if anyone knows better recommendation instead of QT that works with C++ and can do this job.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at QCustomPlot library. It consists of one .cpp and one .h file. Easy to use.
You still have to do your math though, it only helps you plot a set of x, y coordinates.

Comment: Okay I will check it, thank you

Comment: qt chart  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a library that interprets mathematical expressions (i.e: [muparser](https://beltoforion.de/en/muparser/)). In the code i did my own math, but you will be doing that using a library. Considering you managed all those; with QCustomPlot you can draw your graphs.
Here's a sample to give an idea how you can use QCustomPlot:

```
/** I copy pasted the code from one of my projects, please ignore function & class namings
 */
/** somewhere in your window constructor, create a QCustomPlot
 * widget and add graphs to your QCustomPlot widget.
 * example: ui->plt_freq_domain->addGraph();
 */

void ControllerMain::plot_frequency_domain()
{
    QVector <double> vec_keys(1024), vec_values(1024);
    //fill x axis values with incrementing numbers from 0 to 1024 (or any other number you want)
    // let's say your function is y = x^2 and calculate all y values and store them in vec_values
    for(int i = 0; i < vec_keys.size(); i++)
    {
        vec_values[i] = std::pow(vec_keys[i], 2);
    }
    
    // we fill keys with continuous integers [0,1023] so our graph spans along x-axis
    std::iota(vec_keys.begin(), vec_keys.end(), 0); 

    ui->plt_freq_domain->graph(0)->setData(vec_keys, vec_values, true);
    ui->plt_freq_domain->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(QColor(245, 197, 66)));

    ui->plt_freq_domain->yAxis->setLabel("A/m"); // change it with your unit or just keep empty
    ui->plt_freq_domain->yAxis->setRange(*std::min_element(vec_values.begin(), vec_values.end()), 
                                                            *std::max_element(vec_values.begin(), vec_values.end()));

    ui->plt_freq_domain->xAxis->setLabel("f"); // change it with your unit or just keep empty
    ui->plt_freq_domain->xAxis->setRange(vec_keys.constFirst(), vec_keys.constLast());

    ui->plt_freq_domain->replot();
}
```